# Delete DB table item with HTML button in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Can some one point me in the right direction, I'm trying do delete item from user "favorite articles" table. Module works like that: in table: `id`, `user_Id`, `article_Id` and `article_link`.
Article "save" function works no problem. Then I did "delete" button next to each entry, but i don't know how to process it. My guess is through that:

```
public static function delete_art(){
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $query = 'DELETE FROM #__cdart WHERE id = *SOMF HERE!*';
    $db->setquery($query);
    $db->query();
}
```

but I don't know how to tell which article "delete" button did user press...

Update:
Buttons made like that:\

```
<div class="fapa_box">
                    <?php foreach ($getFapList as $getFap): ?>
                    <div class="fapa<?php if(modCdFapaHelper::pageExists() === $getFap->fap_id) echo ' fapa_active'; ?>" id="fapa_<?php echo $getFap->fap_id; ?>">
                        <span class="fapa_icon ui-icon ui-icon-star">&nbsp;</span><a class="fapa_tooltip" href="<?php echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', $getFap->fap_link); ?>" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($getFap->fap_note); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($getFap->fap_title); ?></a>
        <form name="fapa_delete" action="" method="post">
        <?php echo JHTML::_('form.token'); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="fapa" value="remove" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">delete</button>
        </form>

                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to make the buttons?

Comment: the delete button should contain that article id first get that id then you can delete easily.

Comment: plaese explain it, 'button contain'?